# GitHub Pages no me permite abrir mi pagina web

Tags: github-pages

les comento es la primera vez que utilizo GitHub Pages para subir mi pagina.
Estos son los pasos que seguì para intentar hacerlo:

1. subì el repositorio a GitHub publico y le cambie el nombre a "username.github.io"
2. git clone https://github.com/username/username.github.io
3. luego hice `$ cd username.github.io`
4. tambien hice `$ echo "Hello World" index.html`
5. luego hice `$ git add --all`
6. luego `git commit -m "Initial commit"`
7. luego `git push -u origin main`
8. al ingresar a la url `https://username.github.io/` me aparece asì la web...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que yo quiero es poder subir correctamente el repositorio a github page para que desde cualquier pc con la url que me brinda github page poder mostrar mi portfolio a otras personas.

Alguien me podria ayudar? estuve buscando videos para resolverlos.. algunos me dicen que tiene que coincidir los nombres de los archivos index y me parece que coinciden, desde ya muchas gracias ojala alguine me de una mano! (ES LA PRIMERA VEZ QUE USO STACKOVERFLOW) acepto todas las criticas constructivas posibles,

Saludos a toda la comunidad!

Comment: Pero ese `Hello World` te lo da por defecto github o es tuyo?

Comment: Ese Hello World me lo dio por defecto github